# Cypress not finding data-test element

Tags: cypress

Morning/evening everyone. Have a weird issue that, according to the best practices, should just work.
I have the following element on a page which I need to click:

`<a data-test="sign-out-link" href="/redirect/onejl/sign-out"><span>Sign out</span></a>`

I'm doing this in my test:

`cy.get('[data-test="sign-out-link"]') .should('be.visible') .click()`

But cypress times out saying the element cannot be found...

This gives the same behaviour:
`cy.get('a[data-test="sign-out-link"]') .should('be.visible') .click()`

Even this just fails, which is kinda weird (it should find that text fairly easily):

`cy.contains('Sign out').click()`

Anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is not found, is it the element or the href value it's trying to redirect to? Try without the click().

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to find out this element in selector playground. [check here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/selector-playground-api.html#Syntax).
One obvious error I see is on your hyperlink. Try with below

```
cy.get('a[data-test=sign-out-link]').should('be.visible').click()
```

Comment: Thanks, I have used the playground and it only seems to find the header component that this particular link is in. If I enter the data attribute, the link isn't found...

BTW, thanks for the tip, I definitely made an error including the double-quotes, I just pasted the element text directly. But it's still not found, so not sure what to try next.

Comment: Is there any request that is waiting to complete for the link to appear, I mean you can see that from dev tools of the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add a small `cy.wait()` before cypress Sign out test code and see if that is working for you.

```
    cy.wait(2000);
    cy.get('[href="/redirect/onejl/sign-out"] > span').contains("Sign out").click();

    cy.wait(2000);
    cy.get('a > span').contains("Sign out").click();

    cy.wait(2000);
    cy.get('[data-test ="sign-out-link"]').should('be.visible').click();
```